# Where to obtain and how to score the Bukowski et al "Friendship Qualities Scale"?

Tags: social-psychology, measurement

Where to obtain the Bukowski Friendship Qualities Scale?
How do you calculate the scores from it?

It might be available here but I'm not sure because I don't have access to the article: http://spr.sagepub.com/content/11/3/471.short

Bukowski, W. M., Hoza, B., & Boivin, M. (1994). Measuring friendship quality during pre-and early adolescence: The development and psychometric properties of the Friendship Qualities Scale. Journal of Social and Personal Relationships, 11(3), 471-484.

Comment: Not sure of the kind of friendship you are talking about, but for romantic love there's this test: http://www.prenhall.com/divisions/hss/app/social/chap10_1.html

Comment: Question has now been edited to focus on how to obtain and how to score. Obviously as the previous comments noted, this is not a site for requesting pdfs.

Answer (score 2):

**Obtaining:** Yes, the items are listed in Bukowski et al (1994). See Table 1.
You could always email the author explaining your research project and ask him whether he would allow you to use the measure.

**Scoring**:
A quick look suggests that each item is scored on a 1 to 5 scale.
Table 1 suggests that there is a scale-level, and subscale-level of scoring (i.e., 5 scales, and 10 subscales). Table 1 shows how items relates to scales and subscales.

Scoring scales and subscales seems to be just a matter of getting the mean of constituent items.

#### References

- Bukowski, W. M., Hoza, B., & Boivin, M. (1994). Measuring friendship quality during pre-and early adolescence: The development and psychometric properties of the Friendship Qualities Scale. Journal of Social and Personal Relationships, 11(3), 471-484.